# Why Chebotarev's density theorem implies $ \exists {v \in Ω_L}$ such that $Gal(L_v/K_{v'})$ is generated by $\sigma^2$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number field.
Let $Gal(L/K)$ is generated by $\sigma$.

> Why Chebotarev's density theorem implies $ \exists {v \in Ω_L}$ such
> that $Gal(L_v/K_{v'})$ is generated by $\sigma^2$ ? Here, $L_v$ and
> $K_v'$ is completion of $L$ and $K'$ at $v$ and $v'$.  $v'$ is
> restriction of $v$ to $K$.

Chebotarev's dentisty theorem I know is a Theorem $13.4$ of Neukirhi, algebraic number theory,chapter $Ⅶ$, which reads

> Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension. Let $G$ be its Galois group. Then,
> for arbitrary $\sigma\in G$, there exists density of
> $P_{L/K}(\sigma)=\{I \in P(K)\mid$ I is unratified with
> $[\frac{L/K}{I}]=\sigma\}$, whose value is
> $\frac{\sharp〈\sigma〉}{\sharp{G}}$.

There may be another version of Chevotalef density theorem which fits in this context, but I'm wonder why this kind of global field statement implies titles statement(local field case).

Comment: What did you try? The idea is to use the fact that the Galois group of unramifed extension of  local fields is generated by the Frobnious element, and that the "global" Frobnious is the "local" one.